# How can I express this, "When sword emitted fire"

Tags: synonyms, book-title

I have to decide a title, I want to convey of the idea of a legendary sword which emits fire/ befalling curse on the enemies. I want a more impressive word for emitted. And also I need a "when" so I can't just change the title to "The Sword Which emitted Fire".

Comment: If you are searching for a title, I would suggest "The Magic Sword."

Comment: This question makes very little sense to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Erupting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/erupting) [Épée](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/epee)?
The [Blazing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blazing) [Broadsword](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/broadsword)?
The [Flaming](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flaming) [Falchion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/falchion)?
The [Conflagrant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conflagrant) [Claymore](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/claymore)?
The [Fiery](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fiery) [Foil](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foil)?
The [Sputtering](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sputtering) [Spadroon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spadroon)?
The [Simmering](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/simmering) [Scimitar](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scimitar)?
The [Sizzling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sizzling) [Sabre](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sabre)?

Answer (score 0):

When the Sword Erupted Fire

also try [this](http://thesaurus.com/browse/emitted)

Comment: Or just "When the Sword Erupted" or "When the Sword Flamed"

Answer (score 0):

You could say *When the Sword Spits Fire*.

One [definition of spit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spit) is "*(of a fire, hot fat, etc.)* to eject (fragments of coal, sparks, etc.) violently and with an explosive sound; splutter."

(If you put it in the past tense -- "When the Sword Spat Fire" -- it doesn't have the same pizazz, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try "the sword that SPEWED fire."

The word "spew" means particularly to eject forcefully or in large amounts. In fact, you will find that the [Free Online Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spew) illustrates the word this way: "The volcano spewed burning lava."

As for the "When", you could go for a "The Day the Earth Stood Still" feel and write: "THE DAY the sword spewed fire."